# Term for taking an authorized brief leave from work to do a personal errand

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

What do you call when you take a short leave from your workplace (like forty minutes or a couple, of hours) with from your boss' permission, to do a personal errand, like picking up an urgent parcel or something of the like, at any given time during the workday (not necessarily at noon) and then return to your workplace.

Is it a "short leave",  a "time off", "a break"?

A break is for relaxing, and both "short leave" and "time off" sound more like a matter of days than of hours to me.

Comment: Sounds like an 'extended lunch.'

Comment: @YosefBaskin Well, by "the middle of the day" I didn't mean exactly noon.

Comment: You can take a lunch hour (or two) anytime your boss agrees to it. "Say, I need to fit a doctor visit in today, could be a long hour. If it's okay with you  I'll step out at 10:30 and get back soon as I can."  Notice that no actual yes or no is expected. Works as an email without waiting for the boss to approve.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin It doesn't work that way here in India! Explicit verbal permission from the boss is required. Such short authorised time off is usually unofficial and it is simply called '**permission**'!. Example: "Mr.F disappeared at 2:30pm (rather than 5pm), did he take half day leave?" / "No, he took *permission.*"

Comment: A lot would depend on how the company defined it.  Many salaried people have a lot of control of their time, especially if they are allowed to work from home and things like that. They might just be "juggling around my schedule".  Some might be more formal in terms of "hours" and have definitions of "flex time" allowing you to make up hours outside of normal business hours ?

Comment: Mary, I'm going to take some personal time.  I'll be back by 2:00 in case anyone is looking for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many workplaces "two hours" is not at all a short absence from one's duties. I would call that "taking PTO (*paid time off*)". You are using two hours of your accumulated PTO. See [PTO Pros and Cons](https://www.thebalance.com/paid-time-off-policy-pto-1918232):

> Whether they need the time for doctor's appointments, kid's school conferences, to pick Johnny up at the bus stop, to wait for a furnace repairman, or to recover from the flu, the time use is no longer the business of the employer.

Companies that utilize PTO are pretty flexible in granting it, but not all will grant PTO requests of less than half a day (4 hours).

Comment: Thanks! And what do you call paid days off you accrue when you do on call duty? (24/7 phone availability with possible on site presence if incidences cannot be solved remotely) ?

Comment: I doubt I can be much help with that (never encountered it). But it could be somenthung very much like the PTO system. Maybe *Paid Days Off* if you only accrue actual (8-hour?) days off and not a bank of hours (instead of hours). Ask your HR rep?

Comment: Mine is a linguistic enquiry, not a HHRR one. I master the HHRR jargon in my native language. I just want the correct english expression, commonly used in english speaking countries.

Comment: It could be *overtime*, it could be *putting in some flex time* or *putting in extra hours*.